# Is it possible to host AEM pages on an outside server?

Tags: routes, aem, reverse-proxy, aem-6

The company has a marketing website powered by AEM. The company wants to hire an outside agency to build a custom landing page, and we want the code for that page to be hosted elsewhere. Does AEM support this? Perhaps Dispatcher can act as a proxy for certain paths?

Ex:

- companysite.com/normal-page --> AEM Publish instance
- companysite.com/custom-landing-page --> Different, non-AEM server

To be clear, I'm not interested in a *redirect*. I know there are many ways to achieve this. I want to make the content from the outside server available on the main domain.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

It looks like Dispatcher might support this with the configuration property called `/renders`. [The documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/configuring/dispatcher-configuration.html#defining-page-renderers-renders) talks about configuring multiple servers behind the load-balancer, but it doesn't say anything about whether non-AEM instances are supported.

Comment: The renders in dispatcher are for AEM instances. Not sure if you can use it for non-AEM servers. On the other hand, you can achieve this through the web server, i.e., Apache or IIS depending on what is used in your setup.

Comment: The dispatcher is intended to work with the AEM publish instance. What about an iframe?

Comment: The Dispatcher config docs for farms says: "One or more service URLs (*typically* of AEM publish instances) to use for rendering documents." Why is it worded this way if it's only for AEM publish instances? Source: https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/configuring/dispatcher-configuration.html#defining-farms-farms

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of  setting up a relatively simple reverse proxy, provided that you can provide clear routing rules on what goes to AEM and what doesn't... but make sure you consider the various ways the decision you make now will affect your architecture in the longer term.

I've used Apache [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) this way. In that setup, we had an additional Apache server that sat in front of an AEM stack hosted by Adobe Managed Services and a legacy web application that shared the same set of domains (market-specific sites). The decision was made based on the URL. Long story short, depending on your exact setup, desired flexibility and security context, you may choose a different approach.

A very similar thing should be easily achievable at the CDN level. This may differ between providers but a few lines of custom VCL on Fastly (which uses Varnish internally) could do the trick.

In fact, on one of my recent projects, we used both of the above solutions to some extent, depending on the use case. Keep in mind that, while the configuration itself can be quite simple, this comes at a maintenance cost. It helps to have the whole setup mirrored in developer environments. We were lucky enough to have it fully automated so we could quickly spin up and discard environments in AWS. It was quite complex and I'd say a lot of projects don't need to (and shouldn't) get this advanced.

It's hard to tell without knowing your infrastructure (On premise AEM? AMS? AEM in the cloud? Are other applications involved?) but I'd consider starting with a basic `mod_rewrite` config on Apache (same one that has the Dispatcher module installed).

Depending on what that other web application does, providing the right routing rules could be anything between trivial and impossible. Clear separation by path would be very helpful. Remember that you'll most likely be dealing not just with pages but all kinds of resources that those pages load.

Another challenge will be to design the caching in a way that makes sense. Scaling can be yet another factor affected by these decisions.

Comment: Thanks! It sounds like there are easier, better ways to get this done using Apache or a CDN... But out of curiosity, are you able to confirm that AEM's Dispatcher _can't_ be configured to do this? Now I'm mostly curious to understand why the config docs for farms says: "One or more service URLs (typically of AEM publish instances) to use for rendering documents." This suggests it could be something other than AEM instances. Do you understand this? Source: https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/configuring/dispatcher-configuration.html#defining-farms-farms

Answer (score 1):

The dispatcher module is basically an extension for your webserver that takes care of the communication between AEM and the webserver.

Usually you have at least two or more AEM publish servers (each with their own web server) and a loabdalancer or CDN in fron of the webservers.

Apache's mod_proxy is perfectly able to direct requests based on path, ... to different servers without the customer noticing it (no redirect or roundtrip).
Same can be done with any LB or CDN. It does not make sense to route requests through all your infrastructure until they come to the dispatcher module and then get the content from somewhere else if it can be done on a much earlier stage.

On top of that, why bother the dispatcher with irrelevant stuff - it should concentrate on caching AEM pages and keeping those caches up to date (how would you tell the dispatcher to invalidate the cache for your remote content anyway).

My advice would be to handle the requests for the external content as early as possible to reduce the overhead.

BR,
Oliver

Comment: What you said makes sense. The project I'm working on has political constraints that govern the "new" infrastructure that we can introduce into the stack. (These "rules" aren't written by engineers... ;-) Meanwhile, the better reason we were considering this wacky approach is the authoring/admin experience of creating pages/sites outside of AEM. We were hoping for a way to let authors quickly configure these "external nodes" without a devOps engineer reconfiguring the CDN or Apache each time. We were hoping for a way to leverage the AEM GUI for this.

Comment: Got your point. Well, you can always write your own proxy servlet in AEM, but this looks like a really weird thing to do. Then there is https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/redirect-map-manager/index.html which allows editors to generate Apache level redirects in AEM - but redirects won't help you either. From an architectural point of view I really think generating additional traffic for webservers just by adding urls in an application like AEM will lead to disaster - and maybe to an operations team that might not want to support the infrastructure any more.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but at the cdn level. The cdn can be configured for particular url to hit a different server or route.

Hope it helps.